# What is my mistake

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

Spot my mistake:

$$\frac{\left(\text{P}_1+\text{P}_2+\dots+\text{P}_n\right)-\left(\text{Z}_1+\text{Z}_2+\dots+\text{Z}_n\right)}{n-m}\le-\ln(50)$$
$$-\frac{\left(\text{P}_1+\text{P}_2+\dots+\text{P}_n\right)-\left(\text{Z}_1+\text{Z}_2+\dots+\text{Z}_n\right)}{n-m}\le\ln(50)$$
$$\frac{\left(\text{Z}_1+\text{Z}_2+\dots+\text{Z}_n\right)-\left(\text{P}_1+\text{P}_2+\dots+\text{P}_n\right)}{n-m}\le\ln(50)$$
$$\exp\left[\frac{\left(\text{Z}_1+\text{Z}_2+\dots+\text{Z}_n\right)-\left(\text{P}_1+\text{P}_2+\dots+\text{P}_n\right)}{n-m}\right]\le50$$

Comment: The second line ! You should change the inequality sign also

Comment: You multiply by $-1$ without reversing the inequality sign.

Answer (score 2):

$a\leq b\iff -a \geq -b$. You forgot to invert your inequality.

Answer (score 2):

When multiplying or dividing by a negative value, the direction of the inequality is inverted.